# Prove that $A = \{x\in V: \|x\| \leq 1\}$ is always the closure of the open ball $B = \{x \in V: \|x\| < 1\}$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $(V, \|\cdot\|)$ be any normed vector space.

> **Question:**
>   How do I prove that $A = \{x\in V: \|x\| \leq 1\}$ is always the closure of the open ball $B = \{x \in V: \|x\| < 1\}$?

I have very little idea as where to start. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Take $$x_n =\frac{x}{\|x\|+\frac{1}{n}}$$ for every $x\in A$, so that $x_n\in B$

Answer (score 4):

Hint:
Take $$x_n =\frac{x}{\|x\|+\frac{1}{n}}$$ for every $x\in A$, so that $x_n\in B$

and $\overline{B}\subset A$ is obvious